# Why does a standard "boilerplate" template contain so many declarations in CSS3?

Tags: html, css, html5boilerplate

This question is geared towards CSS3, I've been looking at a few boilerplate templates and guides and most of them declare a whole lot of attributes before even going into what you want to edit.

- Why is this so? Does declaring all of the usable attributes make the
  browser load faster or something?
- What are the benefits? Why not just use CSS3 "as is" (like just declaring what's being used in the HTML section)?
- And if the underlying attribute changes in further editions, wouldn't
  it mean you would have to constantly keep a check on deprecated
  attributes and keep declaring and changing attributes every once in a while?

Comment: What do you mean by "declaring attributes". Can you give an example?

Comment: Perhaps post an example or two?

Comment: Are you talking about CSS resets?

Comment: I'm referring to boilerplates like HTML5 Boilerplate from http://html5boilerplate.com/

Comment: why do they declare so much stuff, even before the document is even created?

Comment: I have a feeling you're using the terms "declaration" and "attribute" very, very loosely. These two terms have very specific meanings in CSS and HTML respectively. Please clarify.

Comment: I think I am as well. What's the definition for this type of behaviour, then?

Comment: Like, html { font-size: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML5Boilerplate contains a version of [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/). Rather than just reset everything to 0 (i.e. margins, padding etc) it has the minimum set of changes to ensure things have the same settings in all browsers. In their own words:

> “Normalize.css is a customisable CSS file that makes browsers render
>   all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. We
>   researched the differences between default browser styles in order to
>   precisely target only the styles that need normalizing.”

An example of a style used here is:

```
/*
 * 1. Correct text resizing oddly in IE6/7 when body font-size is set using em units
 * 2. Prevent iOS text size adjust on device orientation change, without disabling user zoom: h5bp.com/g
 */

html {
    font-size: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

This fixes some weirdness in older IE, as well as on iOS. This is the sort of thing that you'll likely have a problem with, read loads, find a solution and add in eventually yourself. By using this set of defaults you can avoid a lot of weirdness.

As well as bugs, it includes things you'd likely want anyway:

```
nav ul,
nav ol {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Using a ul in a nav is a common pattern, and you usually don't want bullet points there. This sorts that for you.

In all, I'd recommend using your own custom version of their code – it will save you a lot of annoyance!

Comment: So... what you're saying is that it just helps all the browsers render, say, a <div> or a <p> attribute correctly?

Comment: Also, would you use a template like this, or would it be better off to just create a website "as is", meaning without all these normalizations, etc

Comment: I use a modified version of html5boilerplate, where I've added in much of my own preference, and removed some of their choices. Sites I make work in all browsers without much tweaking – usually I write a site in Chrome, and it will work in IE8+, Firefox, iOS etc without any changes. For IE6 and 7 I sometimes have to add one or two lines of CSS. Without this set of defaults, things would be much harder.

Comment: Also, when minified and gzipped, this CSS is around 3kB, so although there is some hit, it's small in comparison to the size of the rest of your CSS.

Comment: @RichBradshaw Hmm. I understand your point and what you're trying to put forward here, it is troublesome to see things not displaying correctly due to things not being normalized and stuff. I guess a HTML5 Boilerplate is needed (and handy) to have most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want to add CSS3 functionality you can add it to ie5 with javascript(not to say this doesn't come with its cons) with  [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) or [html5shim](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/) .

Also lets examine the definition of the acronym CSS. Cascading Style Sheets. You may declare styles in order of fall back. i. e.

```
body {
    style-1: new browsers (this renders yay!)
    style-2: semi-new browsers (don't understand style-1 I will ignore ahh style2)
    style-3: ie5(me want to crash soon or BOD you. but me not get either 1 or 2 they smart but i think i can work         on style 3)
```

Comment: What are `style-1`, `style-2` and `style-3` supposed to be? If they're three different properties, cascading doesn't apply. If they're the same property repeated thrice, every browser will use `style-3`...